# BrowseDlg fails to load the image

Tags: wix, wix3

I have following code snippet to open a Browse Dialog

```
  <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="500" Y="142" Width="56" Height="20" Text="Browse" />
```

And other publish code to make sure that it calls for default BrowseDlg

```
  <Publish Dialog="InstallLocationDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallLocationDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

However, when I build and click the Browse button, following screen pops up with icons failing to load.

[image]

What would you think is the cause of this?
I have used WixUI_InstallDir and saw the icons.
It is just when I want to call BrowseDlg from my UI that is having issue.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common"/>` by adding it, everything is resolved.